# HA Cluster Pacemaker + CoroSync + PgpoolII + Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Есть ли смысл создавать НА кластер с указанной связкой? Стоит задача настроить репликацию БД и управлении нодами, в том числе ввод новых нод при необходимости.
Собственно Pacemaker и CoroSync это не обсуждается даже, как и Postgres. А вот, что лучше подобрать для репликации и управления бд? При этом общее для кластера хранилище заводить нельзя, каждая нода должна обладать актуальной на данной момент версией таблиц.

Answer (score 0):

А что собственно вложено в "репликации и управления бд"?

Настраивая Pacemaker и CoroSync (это как раз и будет, своего рода, менеджер репликации), в любом случае, нужно будет использовать потоковую репликацию, иначе нет смысла огород городить. Вопрос только в том, какую,  синхронную или асинхронную (все зависит от требований к доступности и целостности данных).

И что именно понимается под управление БД, настройка кластера (в терминалогии PostgreSQL) или работа с самими данными?

Важно: DDL-команды при репликации не передаются, между мастером и репликами, поэтому "легким движением руки" alter system, можно поломать HA-кластер.